# Django Request MiddleWare Not Taking Effect in View

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am working on a solution that is taking a JWT token, finding the associated user, and setting the user in the request to the found user with the token. My middleware looks like this:

```
class UserTokenMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)

        if header_token is not None:
          try:

            token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
            data = {'token': token}
            valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
            user = valid_data['user']
            request.user = user

          except Token.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        print(request.user.auth_token);
        return self.get_response(request)
```

And it works! The auth_token is present! And its added at the bottom of my middleware like so:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    #Added Last
    "app.middleware.UserTokenMiddleware"
]
```

Now here where doesn't work. I am trying to log out by deleted token, and I need the key. So I have this:

```
@action( url_path="logout", detail=False, methods=["get"], renderer_classes=[JSONRenderer])
    def endsession(self, request):
        result = logout(request)
        #request.user.auth_token.delete()
        print("Auth Token") 
        print(request.user.auth_token);
        print(result)
        return Response({"logout": "successful"})
```

Except I always get the following error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /v1/users/logout
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'auth_token'
```

Any clue to why the auth_token is suddenly disappearing and reverting to AnonymousUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `logout` at the start of the view; that specifically sets the user to anonymous.